# Array to string conversion Template Error

Tags: matrix, array

I have 2 bits of code that should be about identical with the exception of one being in a Matrix and one not. The bit that is not looks like this:

```
<ul>
    {% for point in entry.keyPoints %}
        <li>
            <div class="a-ico">
                <i class="fa fa-{{ point.icon }}"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="a-info">
                <h4>{{ point.heading }}</h4>
                {{ point.text }}
            </div>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This works exactly as intended. and uses the "ICON" 3rd-party field type which essentially is a dropdown that allows me to pick which icon I want to use.

The code that i'm having trouble with is:

```
{% for block in entry.articleBody %}
    {% if block.type == "text" %}
         Some stuff here
    {% elseif block.type =="iconSection" %}
        {% if block.getPrev() %}
            {% if block.getPrev().type != "iconSection" %}
                <ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            <ul>
        {% endif %}
        <li>
            <div class="a-ico">
                <i class="fa fa-{{ block.icon }}"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="a-info">
                <h4>{{ block.heading }}</h4>
                {{ block.text }}
            </div>
        </li>
        {% if block.getNext() %}
            {% if block.getNext().type != "iconSection" %}
                </ul>
            {% endif %}
        {% else %}
            </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% elseif block.type =="video" %}
        some stuff here
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

It is saying Template Error (Array to String Conversion) with this bit highlighted:

```
<i class="fa fa-{{ block.icon }}"></i>
```

As you can see the code is almost identical except it is BLOCK instead of POINT, and the block one is in a matrix where as the point item is not. What might be causing this and how might I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [docs for the Icons plugin](https://github.com/fruitstudios/Icons/#usage), `icon` is actually an **object**. Try this instead...

```
<i class="fa {{ block.icon.class }}"></i>
```

In both scenarios, I'd take another look at your rendered HTML... your first example may actually be rendering the word `Array` instead of the class name that you are looking for. You can also leave off the leading `fa-`, since that will be automatically included in the class name.

Where you have called `icon` in both examples, you're simply referring to *the field itself*. You actually want to be referring to the *values of the field*.

To output the HTML you're looking for, either of these two options will work:

1. `{{ block.icon.icon }}`
2. `<i class="fa {{ block.icon.class }}"></i>`

And for your non-matrix example, just replace `block` with `point`.

Comment: This worked, any idea why it worked without that in one instance and required it in another?

Comment: Are you sure the `point` instance was generating the right HTML code? (Was the icon actually showing up?) According to the plugin docs, that code snippet shouldn't have worked.

Comment: Yep, showed up and worked EXACTLY as intended.